# Silence a warning in TAP

Tags: perl, testing

My code has a test for a bad API call, fortunately that code results in a warning from the module itself. But when I'm testing the failed API call I want to not see the warning in TAP.

```
t/01-pass.t .............. ok
t/02-fail.t .............. ok
t/03-noversion.t ......... ok
t/04-no-file.t ........... ok
Use of uninitialized value $file in concatenation (.) or string at /home/xenoterracide/projects/Test-Version/lib/Test/Version.pm line 29.
t/05-file-not-defined.t .. ok
# unsorted oks: 001
t/06-all.t ............... ok
All tests successful.
Files=6, Tests=37,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.02 sys +  0.35 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.45 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Here's the actual code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Tester tests => 7;
use Test::Version qw( version_ok );

check_test(
    sub {
        version_ok; # correct call version_ok( $file )
    },
    {
        ok => 0,
        name => 'check version in ',
        diag => 'FILE_NOT_DEFINED',
    },
    '$file not defined'
);
```

is there any way to squelch the warning and prevent to prevent it from ending up in TAP *(outside of `no warnings` in the original module)*.

Comment: You should fix the code so it doesn't throw a warning when it's given improper arguments.

Comment: @schwern why? it'll give up and fail the test anyways, which is what it should do. The code is not supposed to work without an argument... all I want to know is that the test properly returns in failure

Comment: @xenoterracide 1) it indicates a situation the code hasn't really considered, that it works may be a coincidence.  2) since you're not throwing an exception (it probably should be throwing an exception), in production you're going to get that warning and clog up the logs and distract the reader with it rather than the real problem.  3) you have to do just as much work to suppress the warning (and *just* that warning) in the test as fixing it. 4) if you don't and just turn off all warnings for that run you might be obscuring another important warning later.

Comment: @schwern I disagree that it would be just as much work, and no it should not throw an exception. It's a simple testing module, if the api is called wrong it needs to fail. which is what this whole test asks... does the test fail if you use the API wrong. Unfortunately it also throws a warning if you use the API wrong. However, to fix that and otherwise have the same results I have now I would have to introduce significant complexity in how $name is defined, to avoid appending the parameter $file for just when the API is called wrong. seems like a waste of time. Patches welcome.

Comment: @xenoterracide Looking at your code, sanitize the input with `$file ||= ''` and you're done. https://github.com/schwern/Test-Version/commit/7053bcd905015638ff44398ccfb4d5d090555d7d  I've also patched up a bunch of other little problems with the test. https://github.com/xenoterracide/Test-Version/pull/1  Its worth putting a little effort into cleaning up warnings *especially* in a valid API call (you're treating it as a normal test failure rather than an exception, so its valid).  They usually go away with simple input sanitizing, which is a good practice to get into.

Comment: @schwern man that makes me feel dumb.. I had some complicated ternary going on in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {};
```

will silence warnings temporarily.

Comment: simple, works, doesn't require me to add a whole bunch of other dependencies or figure out any new code, and easily restricted to the area just above the function call.

Comment: I would recommend against a blanket turning off of all warnings for the code.  You suppress one known warning now, but changes might introduce more later and you'll never see it.  Suppressing warnings is a very slippery slope and should not be taken lightly.

Comment: @xenoterracide: If you're going to do this I'd change the handler to `sub { push @warnings, @_ }` (with `@warnings` defined outside the sub) and check that it contains *only* your expected warning for a given test. Of course, at that point you might as well just use Test::Warn, or prevent the warning in the first place.

Comment: @schwern it should be localized to the area where I placed it. but reality is the Test::Tester test is otherwise so simple I'm not really concerned... this is not something I plan to do often.

Answer (score 6):

You're possibly looking for [Test::Warn](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aWarn). It's easy to use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Test::Warn;
# You might also find the following modules interesting:
# use Test::Exception;
# use Test::NoWarnings;

sub bla { warn 'bla' }

warning_is { bla() } 'bla';
done_testing;
```

So you're transforming the warning from a nuisance into something expected.

If this is not what you want, then take a look at [IO::CaptureOutput](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCaptureOutput) or - *de préférence*, according to the author of both modules, David Golden - at [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Capture-Tiny/).

You could also code everything by hand redirecting STDERR to buffer for the time you're making the call that'll emit the warning.

Comment: Test::Warn is for testing that an expected warning happens.  That is, a warning that's part of the interface.  The OP's warning is not that, it's a proper warning telling the OP that the code was not well written to handle getting no argument.

Comment: @Schwern, you're right. Looks like for the OP's case, `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {}` is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: I would do this if it weren't for the fact that I would then have to figure out how to get this inside of a Test::Tester test. I put `local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {};` right above `version_ok` in that block. However wrapping a sub, that wraps a sub that wraps a sub or whatever was hurting my brain. Also I wasn't sure that I wanted to add yet another dependency for one test. @schwern patches welcome to Test::Version to fix version_ok so that it doesn't generate a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Another warning-related module to consider is [Test::NoWarnings](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-NoWarnings/).  This checks that your code produces no warnings, and will fail a test if not. You can ignore known warnings, such as the OP's, assuming that is the desired behaviour (at $work we ignore warnings from a handful of 'noisy' CPAN modules, such as PDF::API2). It can

In general I'd agree with Schwern though, and try and fix warnings rather than a blanket `$SIG{__WARN__}` override. One of the main benefits of tests is catching errors introduced when *other* code is changed - your test file is not just checking that the code you've just written is ok, but that the code you've written will still be ok in the future when CPAN modules and the rest of your app will have been updated.

Comment: I agree that in general it's a bad idea. Everyone has kind of lost focus that this is one of 6 tests written specifically for this module (meaning no one bothered to go read Test::Version) and that **only** one of them have I done this in. This one test is to check an bad api call and that diagnostics are printed right for that.

I could add Test::NoWarnings to a good run of the API that's supposed to work and it would run just fine. Basically the whole test was to say that the code written is **not** just fine and that the test fails appropriately.